# Pegar valor de uma celula[0] de um .data()

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu consegui puxar todos os dados da minha linha selecionada. Mas eu quero acessar somente o valor de uma propriedade, como por exemplo `id_produto`. Como faço?

Já consegui imprimir todos os dados no console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 var table = $('#tbl_estoque').DataTable( {
  "ajax": "data.php",
  "bPaginate":true,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "pageLength": 5,

  
  "columns": [
   { mData: 'cod_produto' } ,
   { mData: 'cat_produto' },
   { mData: 'descricao_produto' },
   { mData: 'qnt_total' },
   { mData: 'qnt_vendido' },
   { mData: 'valor_produto' },
   { mData: 'valor_total' },
   {defaultContent: "<button>Click!</button>"}
  ]
 }); 
 $('#tbl_estoque tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log( table.row( this ).data() );

} );
 $('#btn_load').click( function () {
  table.ajax.reload(null, false);
 }); 
});
```

Após colocar o console.log( table.row( this ).data('id_produto') );
olha o console como ficou:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ao invés de usar uma foto, poste o código em formato de texto usando a formatação de bloco de código. :)

Comment: Desculpe! Coloquei o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme mostra a [documentação do método `data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2), você pode passar uma **chave** como primeiro argumento e o valor correspondente será retornado.

Você também pode usar a notação de acessar propriedades de um [objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos) (`obj.propName`).

Um exemplo que tange as duas possibilidades mencionadas:

```js
const $el = $('time')

console.log($el.data())

// Usando a API do jQuery:
console.log($el.data('country'))

// Através da notação de objeto:
console.log($el.data().timezone)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<time data-country="BR" data-timezone="-3">22:00</time>
```

Portanto, você pode fazer:

```
console.log( table.row( this ).data('id_produto') );
```

Comment: não deu certo, postei o resultado na pergunta

Comment: Tente fazer assim: `table.row( this ).data().id_produto`. Funciona?

Comment: Deu certinho. Porém quando eu faço: document.getElementById("categoria").value = table.row( this ).data().cat_produto; que no caso ele escreve no meu select de id=categoria o valor da celula. ELE NAO ESCREVE NO SELECT. Somente nos input text. O que pode ser?